# Python: making make_class TypeError: object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I have this problem while making my simple make_class. Here is my code:

```
def make_class(attrs, class_name, base=None):
    def get(name):
        if name in attrs:
            return attrs[name]
        elif base:
            return base['get'](name)

    def set(name, value):
        attrs[name] = value

    return cls
```

Running the program -

```
def make_user():
    return make_class('Test', {'code': 0.202})


def make_user_class():
    def init(self, owner):
        self['set']('name', owner)
        self['set']('number1', 0)

    return make_class(Test, 'TUser', {'__init__': init, 'code': 0.03})


Test = make_user()
TAccount = make_user_class()
Test['get']('name')
```

I tried to set the value in the def set(name, value): function but then it says

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 276, in
>
> Test = make_user()   File "main.py", line 265, in make_user
> return make_class('TAccount', {'interest': 0.202})   File "main.py", line 259, in make_class
> cls['set']('class_name', class_name)   File "main.py", line 232, in set
> attrs[name] = value TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Your code is indented incorrectly. Please [edit] your question. Also see [mre].

Comment: can you make a minimal reproducible example of your error? also, post the whole error message

Comment: @DapperDuck that is probably just due to posting it incorrectly to stackoverflow, happens all the time

Comment: @oskros Indeed, I just don't want to edit the question, if that is what the mistake is.

Comment: What is supposed to be the purpose of this code?

Comment: @zvone Output: 'Test'

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to provide the **full** error traceback, the current output, and the expected output.

Comment: @Alon I don't understand. The purpose of this weird code is _"Output: 'Test'"_? That makes even less sense that the code itself ;)

Comment: You aren't passing arguments to `make_class` in the ordered required by the definition. Attribute dictionary first, then the class name, then the optional base class. If you want to pass them in an arbitrary order, you need to use keyword arguments.

Comment: I'm guessing your error is here: `attrs[name] = value`, but it's hard to tell what your code is trying to do at first glance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the signature you used to define `make_class`:

```
def make_class(attrs, class_name, base=None):
```

When you call `make_class`, the positional arguments need to be in the correct order:

```
def make_user():
    return make_class({'code': 0.202}, 'Test')


def make_user_class():
    def init(self, owner):
        self['set']('name', owner)
        self['set']('number1', 0)

    return make_class({'__init__': init, 'code': 0.03}, 'TUser', Test)
```

Note that having `make_user_class` refer to a predefined global `Test` probably isn't a great idea. `make_user_class` itself should probably take the desired base class as an argument itself:

```
def make_user_class(base):
    def init(self, owner):
        self['set']('name', owner)
        self['set']('number1', 0)

    return make_class({'__init__': init, 'code': 0.03}, 'TUser', base)


Test = make_user()
TAccount = make_user_class(Test)
Test['get']('name')
```